# Token Authentication Do's and Dont's

Tags: json, api, rest, authentication, token

We need to setup an App-Server Communication with an Rest-API providing json on the server side.

We want to send a token to the server to authenticate the app. It is required to use HTTPS, so that the connection is encrypted.
But we are quiet unclear about how to do it. A few questions came up:

**Can I send the token with a GET request?** or is the token only encrypted by HTTPS if I send it with a POST request?

**Where do I put the token?** Is the token just another parameter of my json array of do I have to put it in the HTTP Header? (I heard of this, but don't have an idea how to do it?)

**When do I use a POST and when do I use a GET request?**
My assumption is to use GET if I (as the app) want a list of objects or a single object and use POST if I want to give an object to the server, that the server needs to save.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens are typically sent in the `Authorization` HTTP header of the request, no matter which verb you are using.

Sending the token as a query parameter is possible, but usually frowned upon. 
The complete request, including query parameters is encrypted when using HTTPS, but the request URL including query parameters may be logged at the web server, potentially leaking the token.

In good REST APIs, you use GET to retrieve resources from the server and POST to create new resources or change state of resources on the server.

See also [this article](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/).